# How to package JRuby programs for Windows as one-click executables

Tags: windows, executable, jruby

I'm porting a Ruby program to Windows, and I really need a super-simple package - something that user downloads, unzips, doubles clicks the obvious program file, and it's running. Without having to install JRuby, or even Java if it's possible.

Or possibly downloads, runs installer, confirms a few silly questions, and selects obvious program from start menu, if the first option is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269164/create-deployable-jruby-jar) may help.