# Create a ruby executable with wxruby for linux

Tags: ruby, linux, executable, wxruby

I want distribute a application build with ruby and wxruby, but i cant generate one executable, try with ocra , AllInOneRuby but Windows support only and try with rubyscript2exe, but have much errors and doesnt run.

[edit]

With rubyscript2exe first i got 
rubyscript2exe:5:in replace': can't modify frozen string (TypeError)
but i have a solution

later i got require': undefined method `unresolved_deps' for Gem:Module

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require': undefined method `unresolved_deps' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:28
Couldn't execute this command (rc=256):
/usr/bin/ruby -r 'enumerator.so' -r 'rubygems/defaults.rb' -r 'rbconfig.rb' -r 'rubygems/deprecate.rb' -r 'rubygems/exceptions.rb' -r 'rubygems/custom_require.rb' -r 'rubygems.rb' -r 'rubygems/version.rb' -r 'rubygems/requirement.rb' -r 'rubygems/dependency.rb' -r 'rubygems/platform.rb' -r 'rubygems/specification.rb' -r 'rubygems/path_support.rb' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/lib' -I '/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux' -I '/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby' -I '/usr/lib64/site_ruby/1.8' -I '/usr/lib64/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux' -I '/usr/lib64/site_ruby' -I '/usr/lib/ruby/1.8' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8' -I '/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux' -I '.' -I '/home/richie' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe/lib' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe' -I '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe/lib' -r '/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.3642.1/rubyscript2exe/require2lib.rb' 'Dropbox/15M/src/q.rb'  --require2lib-quiet
```

Stopped.

with ruby 1.8.7

any help ?

Comment: What errors?  Context is helpful.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 and rubygems 1.7.2

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Well, that project is over two years out of date.  You're likely going to have to make some changes to the project to make it work.

Comment: edit my post and put my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This may not work, because the wxruby gem may use binary "extensions", and that is platform dependent and so may not be easy to get working in Jruby... try and tell

You can try the following workaround with Jruby + warbler gem - it can package your ruby program into a portable JAR (java) file, which you can then copy and run on other computers that have Java  installed (only java, ruby will already go packaged in the .jar file :) )

I've made some notes for myself some months ago - they should be enough for the steps involved:

#### 1- install jruby

- see http://jruby.org/
- should be as simple as dowload zip file, unzip it, set an environment variable, and execute it (everything is explained it their website, pretty easy)

#### 2- install warbler gem

```
jruby -S gem install warbler
```

#### 3- place your .rb files for compile/package with warbler

(see this StackOverflow thread: [Create deployable JRuby JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269164/create-deployable-jruby-jar/5758996#5758996)  )

```
mkdir myapp  
mkdir myapp/bin
vim   myapp/bin/myapp.rb  #create .rb file which will be 'booted' (executed) by jar file
mkdir myapp/lib
vim   myapp/lib/my_nice_lib.rb #leave all .rb files to be 'require'd here 
cd myapp
```

#### 4- use warbler to compile/package into myapp.jar

```
warble jar
```

#### 5- run myapp.jar in any computer with java, with:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Hope it helps - report back how it went

Cheers

Comment: i try jruby and warbler :), for example works fine, warbler generate a .jar :) , but i have problems with wxruby for jruby. `gem install wxruby` says not found but i can install with `gem install wxruby --platform x86_64-linux`, but i got this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VGfj8UYH)

Comment: sounds like wxruby will not work so easily with jruby because of extensions... if you feel like, you could have a look at 'shoes' or some java-gui-lib like Swing or JavaFx but that will force you more-and-more into java-land...