# JRuby project structure and jar creation

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have to create a JRuby jar file for my project. Below I provided details about my directory structure and files.

1. Top level directory - `Project1`
2. Under `Project1` – I have `bin, lib, src` folders
3. Under `Project1/bin` – I have `wrapper shell script` from where I am calling `jruby jar`.
4. Under `Project1/lib` – I have `jruby-complete-1.6.7.2.jar` and `ojdbc6.jar`
5. Under `Project1/src` – I have `lib` and `tool` folders

   - Under  `Project1/src/lib` – I have `main.rb` file and `util`folder
   - Under  `Project1/src/lib/util` - I have `2-ruby scripts` which are getting called in `main.rb`.
6. Under `Project1/src/tool`- I have `Tool.java` from where I call `main.rb`.

Now I have couple of questions -

1. Do I need to bundle all the gems which I used in my ruby scripts (for example: `colorize`, `socket`, `net/ssh`, etc)?
2. How do I create a JRuby jar? I saw the following [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269164/create-deployable-jruby-jar-file) on stackoverflow before posting my question but I got confused and kind of not able to figure out from where to start. Please provide some guidance on this.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson-Thanks for the answer. That was helpful but I did not need to use warbler in my project. Instead I found it easier to package all the gems into a reusable jar file by following http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar/. But right now I am facing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error while trying to call the jar from the shell script. Can you help me fixing this?

Comment: Usually I answer my questions after finding the solution so that it can be helpful for others like me but I was trying to get the working piece before doing that. Right now I passed next step and trying to fix the other errors. I will post my question if I cannot find the solution in some time. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps which worked for me to bundle all the gems into jruby-complete.jar.

1. Download the jruby-complete-latest_version.jar from `http://jruby.org/download`.
2. Verify which gems are included in the downloaded jar, say `java -jar jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -S gem list`.
3. To push the gems into jruby-complete-latest_version.jar you need to check for all the required runtime dependecies for that gem. Example: for `net-scp` you need to download `net-ssh` gem before.
4. Download the gems under the same directory where you have jruby-complete-latest_version.jar by using the following command:

   `java -jar jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -S gem install -i ./net-ssh net-ssh --no-rdoc --no-ri`
   `java -jar jruby-completelatest_version.jar -S gem install -i ./net-scp net-scp --no-rdoc --no-ri`
5. Now add the gems inside `ruby-complete-latest_version.jar` by using `update file (uf)` option for the jar file. Example: 
   `jar uf jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -C net-ssh .` 
   `jar uf jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -C net-scp .`
6. Check the gem list for the jar file to make sure all the gems are added successfully
   `java -jar jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -S gem list`
7. Last check to make sure gems are loading successfully, run `require` statements on `irb`.

   `java -jar jruby-complete-latest_version.jar -S irb`
   `irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
       => true
       irb(main):002:0> require 'net/scp'
       => true`

After I have the `jruby-complete_latest_version.jar` file under `lib` I used ANT to build the jar for my project.

Again this solution will work for the smaller projects. For big projects Warbler will the best choice as suggested by @joelparkerhenderson.