# How to prevent my users to read my Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I want to prevent my users to read my ruby code.

Are there some efficient tricks to do that (apart from executing my code on a server) ?

Comment: Why particularly do you want to stop them from reading the code? You should note that the tools listed below will not stop someone really determined as they generally contain a copy of the source code within them. The most they will do is obfuscate the code and make it difficult to get to.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to compile Ruby to byte code as with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972388/is-it-possible-to-compile-ruby-to-byte-code-as-with-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jruby you can pack your code in a jar, which makes it less accessible. You've got some options:

- [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921475/compile-jruby-hello-world-problem)
- use [rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/) to package standalone apps, even with UI
- use [warble](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) for packing rails apps

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

There are gems like Tar2RubyScript, RubyScript2Exe which help you distributing your ruby code. You can read http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html for more information