# Protect Ruby code

Tags: ruby, marshalling, ffi, source-code-protection

I'm writing Ruby app and I want to use some top-secret algorithms. So how would be the best to protect them from unauthorized access.

I have 2 ideas:

- write them in C and load using FFI (I wonder if It's possible this way)
- Marshal ruby code, encode it and then store in file

Maybe someone know better idea or can show me that these ideas are stupid or wrong. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Don't distribute the source code? Or is that crazy?

Comment: Do you mean to protect it from your Web Hosting company?

Comment: Top-secret code? Cool. I saw that movie. If you don't trust your customer and can't put in the legalese in your contract that will keep them in line, then don't sell the software to them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent my users to read my Ruby code ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385914/how-to-prevent-my-users-to-read-my-ruby-code)

Comment: It'll be hosted solution but I want to protect it in case someone breaks in. Server would be in our company.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot protect the algorithm  you are writing by changing it to C .. May be you can encrypt the source files. Try [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

**Edit**

After some googling i found these articles related to ruby code obfuscation

1. [protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user-applications/](http://web.archive.org/web/20110828153039/http://seanmountcastle.com/2007/12/protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user-applications/)
2. [Ruby Encoder Protects Source Code for US Department of Defense Project](http://www.prlog.org/10390387-ruby-encoder-protects-source-code-for-us-department-of-defense-project.html)
3. http://rubyencoder.com/

Comment: No offense, but this response is so general. What value does it offer?

Comment: Yeah, it was helpfull. Thanks to this response I found my solution (for now). http://ruby2cext.rubyforge.org/

Comment: the first link is 404 now T^T old archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20110828153039/http://seanmountcastle.com/2007/12/protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can try some code obfuscation techniques. For example [RubyEncoder](http://rubyencoder.com/) compiles Ruby source code into a encrypted bytecode format. And here is another thread related to your question [Ruby obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123437/ruby-obfuscator)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to craft your own solution instead of buying and already made one like [RubyEncoder](http://rubyencoder.com/), as stated on other answer here, there is an [article](http://mountcastle.posterous.com/protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user) that try to describe a method to protect your source code, and you can also implement all sort of protection you think is feasible, as you are going to do all by hand:

http://mountcastle.posterous.com/protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user

Comment: 404 for now, old archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130520100956/http://mountcastle.posterous.com/protecting-your-ruby-source-code-for-end-user