# Is it possible to deploy a Rails application to a server in a way in which even the root can't view the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, packaging

A client is asking me if is it possible to deploy a Rails application on a third-party's server in some way that even the server's administrator cannot get the application source code. May be any kind of packaging with encryption or something like that? I think it's not possible but I want to assure it to him and well, now I'm curious about this question too...

Thanks in advance for any ideas :-)

Comment: I think this question about Ruby obfuscation is relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123437/ruby-obfuscator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question as [How to prevent my users to read my Ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385914/how-to-prevent-my-users-to-read-my-ruby-code)

Top answer there: jruby.

[the ruby encoder](http://rubyencoder.com/) looks like a viable solution, and is targeted at MRI & Rails. That would probably be my first try.

I would also guess Rubinius could be used for obfuscation, since it compiles to bytecode. I've seen it suggested for such use, but haven't seen anyone actually implement a deployment tool for such.